# Are there some forms to use the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible instead of doing **"return view"** in Controller
 Do a **"return  for another action"** in the same controller?
 If possible? So how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, you can do this with

```
return RedirectToAction("another action name");
```